# c# wpf filter list In Statement

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, list, filter

I am working with WPF and  c#. I have a list of objects.  Example: `List<Employee>` and the employee class has a property `departmentID_A` and `departmentID_B`.
The user has a list of `checkbox` with the departments name to filter the list.
I want to filter the list by the "in statement" something like this:
`EmployeeList.Find(p => p.departmentID_A in (1, 2, 3));`
Is any way that I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your filter contains many items you should use

```
var employees = new List<Employee>();
var filter = new HashSet<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

var result = from i in employees
             where filter.Contains(i.DepartmentID_B)
             select i;
```

Note that the LINQ query returns an IEnumerable. It does not filter a list in place. If you want a List or Array you can call `ToList()` or `ToArray()` on your result and you may use pure function calls:

```
var employees = new List<Employee>();
var filter = new HashSet<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

var result = employees.Where(x => filter.Contains(x.DepartmentID_B));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
        List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
        List<int> filter = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

        var result = (from i in employees
                      where filter.Contains(i.DepartmentID_B)
                      select i);
```